# Closing a question: How are migration possibilities determined?

Tags: support, migration

I was going to put a close vote with suggestion to migrate to writers.se on [this question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120054/when-writing-a-formal-report-is-it-bad-to-make-up-names-when-giving-an-example) (about the use of names in formal writing), but when I tried to cast the close vote, the only target for migration that I can choose is Meta.English.

I know that on other questions where I've cast concurring close votes, other targets such as writers and ELL have been listed as options.

Why would it not be an option for me when trying to cast an initial close vote?

Comment: I don't think ELL was ever an option, but you're right that writers.se was there and has now been removed. You can still make your point by closevoting as "OffTopic - > Other", and setting your associated justification comment to something like *This question appears to be off-topic **because it should be on writers.se***

Comment: Is this basically a subset of this question? http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4021/14073

Comment: Yeah, it probably is.  If the other options used to be there and were purposely removed, that's comprehensible (although annoying and arguably a bad choice).  If they show up for some people but not for others, or only under certain circumstances (which was my initial conclusion), that's confounding.  If you are certain that they were simply removed, then this is a duplicate.

Comment: I will add that when casting a "concurring" close vote, there has been the display that "other people have chosen X" and in at least several cases, I was able to follow their choice tree to arrive at "off topic > belongs on another site > ELL".

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it works:

- Meta sites don't have migration options.
- Every main site has the ability to migrate to its meta.
- Moderators can singlehandedly migrate questions to any site, meta or main. Both meta and main questions can be migrated. If you see an off-topic question that was posted within the last 60 days that is on-topic elsewhere, flag it for moderator attention and it can be migrated.
- Users can post a meta question asking for more migration targets to be added. An example of such a request is [Should we have a migration path to ELL?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7128/191178). Migration paths are only created if there are a lot of questions being migrated manually by moderators. Typically, beta sites are not given migration targets nor are they allowed to be a migration target for another site. Currently an exception to that is Writing can migrate questions to ELU (the only exception I'm aware of, actually).
- A site can only have four sites besides its meta as options.

---

ELU has never had the option to migrate to Writing, best I can tell. The migration path to ELL was added September 2015.

Probably what you're thinking of is just the custom reason. Anything within the character limit can be put in it and it will be seen as a suggestion to other close voters as well as being posted as a comment:

> [image]